# converting json into java object for a array with mixed types

Tags: java, json

My json string looks like the following:

```
{
  "text": ["foo",1,"bar","2",3],
  "text1": "value1",
  "ComplexObject": {
   .....
   }
}
```

I have a pojo defined like this:

```
class MyPojo {
 List<String> text;
 String text1;
 ComplexObject complexObject;
}
```

I use google gson and am able to get my java object populated properly. The problem here is that the field text is an array of mixed types (string and int). So all the entries there are converted into String and i am not able to figure out which entries in the array is a string vs int. I cant use parseInt since the entries in the original array may have "2" as well as 3.

Is there a way for me to get the right instance type of the fields in my array after converting into java object.

### SOLUTION

So i implemented the solution using gson the round about way using the JsonDeserializer. And then i tried using jackson. Guess what jackson supports serializing/deserializing the mixed array type by preserving the data types.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
MyPojo gmEntry = mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<MyPojo >(){});
```

And i can basically fetch the List<Object> and do an instanceof to check for the datatype.

Shame on you gson!!

Comment: Tricky situation. Probably you might have tried already but is it not possible to separately maintain the data i.e. strings and numbers ?

Comment: That is correct, i cannot maintain it separately

Comment: The fact that data contains integers as strings as well as integers is not known to gson. Based on List<String> it converts everything into strings. Once thats done, there seems to be no way to get integers alone without getting strings that are actually integers. Looks dead end to me.

Comment: I'm not tied to gson. Are there any other libraries that may help?

Answer (score 1):

By having a custom class and adding a type adapter u can manipulate the string (json.toString() returns with the '"' quotes, so you can see if its a string or not.

Output: (the classes seem correct)

class test.Main$StringPojo pojo{object=foo}

class test.Main$IntPojo pojo{object=1}

class test.Main$StringPojo pojo{object=bar}

class test.Main$StringPojo pojo{object=2}

class test.Main$IntPojo pojo{object=3}

```
public static void main(final String[] args){


    String str = "{\n" +
            "  \"text\": [\"foo\",1,\"bar\",\"2\",3],\n" +
            "  \"text1\": \"value1\" }";

    GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
    builder.registerTypeAdapter(pojo.class, new JsonDeserializer<pojo>() {
        @Override
        public pojo deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
            try {
                return new IntPojo(Integer.parseInt(json.toString()));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return new StringPojo(json.getAsString());
            }
        }
    });
    MyPojo myPojo = builder.create().fromJson(str, MyPojo.class);
    for (pojo pojo : myPojo.text) {
        System.out.println(pojo.getClass() + " " + pojo.object);
    }
}

public static abstract class  pojo{
    protected Object object;

    public pojo() {
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "pojo{" +
                "object=" + object +
                '}';
    }
}

public static class StringPojo extends pojo{
    public StringPojo(String str) {
        object = str;
    }
}

public static class IntPojo extends pojo{

    public IntPojo(int intt) {
        this.object = intt;
    }
}
public static class MyPojo {
    List<pojo> text;
    String text1;
}
```

Comment: Can you please update the codebase with the java 7 equivalent?

Comment: Never mind was able to get this working in java7. This looks to be promising. Let me try this out and will let you know.

Comment: As you are creating the object yourself, you can initialise it how you want (you don't have to use abstract classes), I've edited it so that its java 7

Comment: This is the same I proposed!

Comment: You proposed a data structure, not a way to use the gson to parse mixed types in an array. When running your code with the library being used exceptions were thrown

Comment: So i spent some time and got this working. And then i went and tried doing this with jackson and guess what?? Jackson supports serializing/deserializing mixed array types and preserves the data type. Shame on you gson!!

Answer (score 0):

As you wrote - you defined: `List<String> text;` but that list also contains integers.

Java is strongly typed, please consider to either declare the List as `List<Object>` (less preferable) or creating a JSON list that contains only a single type of variable (more preferable).

Comment: The problem with defining it as a List<Object> is that i'm not able to figure out which elements of the List is an integer vs a string. The getClass() return me java.lang.Object.

Comment: Of course cause that's the type of the List :) this is also the reason that I wrote that it's not the preferable way - you *can* do it but you'll have to do ugly stuff in order to make it work. For example: `Object[] a = {"a", 1};
        System.out.println(Integer.valueOf((String.valueOf(a[1]))));` and then surround it with `try/catch` in case it's not an `int` and etc.

Comment: Like i mentioned in my post, i cant use Integer.valueOf since my json array can have say "3" as well as 2, for e.g. ["3",2]

Comment: You *can* get the JSON as a string and parse it yourself, looking for each item if it's surrounded by quotes or not. But you'll have to implement it instead of being able to use an existing JSON library. As I already said, that's a bad practice and the code would look ugly (as well as maintaining it won't be fun...). A better approach would be to reconsider the architecture and pass JSON arrays that contains the same type. Keep in mind that Java is strongly typed, unlike Javascript/Python/Ruby etc.

Comment: Well guess what jackson supports this interestingly pretty easily.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an abstract class `ItemType` (for use as array item type) and inherits from it two wrapper classes: one for int type and another for string type.

```
abstract class ItemType {
    protected Object value;
}
class IntType extends ItemType {
    IntType(Integer value){
        this.value = value;
    }
}
class StringType extends ItemType {
    IntType(String value){
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Try this `List<ItemType> text;`

Comment: I tried this however it throws an exception "com.google.gson.JsonParseException: Expecting object found: foo"

Comment: The constructor for `StringType` should be `StringType(String value)`

Answer (score 0):

The above situation can be achived by using `TypeAdapter` of Gson API.

Please follow : https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Serializing-and-Deserializing-Collection-with-Objects-of-Arbitrary-Types

Comment: I had a look at that. The example there given is having the array as a top level element. while in my case it's not. So essentially i will have to parse the json string myself and then figure out whether it's a JsonArray or a JsonObject and not be able to take advantage of the direct json to java object conversion benefits. 

Also in the example given it looks like the order of the elements in the array is pre-defined which is not my case.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you need, but this is the code I use for parsing JSON.

```
static public void newsParser(String urlString, String targetObject) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
    {

        URL url = new URL(urlString);

        JSONParser parser=new JSONParser();


           BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));



           Object obj;
        try 
        {
            obj = parser.parse(br);         
            //JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
            JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) obj;

            Iterator<?> i = jsonArray.iterator();

            while (i.hasNext())
            {
                slide = (JSONObject) i.next();
                newsInfo = (String)slide.get(targetObject);   
                System.out.println(newsInfo);
                newsTitles.add(newsInfo);


            }
        } 
        catch (ParseException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```